# Crystal Reports On-Demand Subreport Hyperlink is only working in preview

Tags: crystal-reports

I added a subreport (existing report) to a crystal report as a on-demand subreport. In the report preview the hyperlink to the subreport works fine but if i run my application the hyperlink does not work.

If i insert the subreport not as a on-demand subreport also everything works fine.

Is there anything i have to do, to get the hyperlink to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to SAP this is a bug in the wpf control of crystal reports and will be fixed in version 13.0.22